# If I call dispatch_async in the +load method, will that block be guaranteed to run after all classes have been set up?

Tags: objective-c, class, initialization, dispatch-async

I know that during `+load` other classes may still be getting set up, but I'm curious what happens if you wait for one run loop.

Comment: Even if it did, it seems a bit fragile. Perhaps you can describe the broader objective and there might be other, more robust patterns.

Comment: I want to perform a method at startup to register my object as an observer. This would be easy with NSNotificationCenter since it's loaded when +load is called, but I'm using a third-party listener library, so I have no guarantees.

Comment: Where is the logical place for your observer object to be instantiated? Generally app delegate or something like that. And have the `init` method add itself as an observer, as needed. I wouldn't use `load` for this. If you want more detail, I'd suggest you supply a practical example (e.g. show us one of the things you want to observe, as well as links to this "listener library").